# Example of xargs' -x option in action

Tags: shell, xargs

GNU `xargs` has option '-x'. The man page says:

> -x     Exit if the size (see the -s option) is exceeded.

But `xargs` seems to not care if `-x` is set or not. I have been unable to make an example in which the `-x` has any effect at all.

Please provide two examples in which the only difference is an added `-x` and that produce different output.

Comment: To save future readers time:  If you set a size limit with `-s <byteCount+1>`, xargs will _invariably_ enforce it for you - no `-x` needed. `-x` is only needed if you _additionally_ want to enforce _use of a specified number of arguments per invocation_ (`-n <argCount>`) without breaking the size limit. The [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3027148/45375) does not state that, and also incorrectly implies that `-x` results in processing of _no arguments at all_, if _any_ argument violates the size constraint (a misinterpretation of the effects of a bug in GNU `xargs` 4.2.2).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set a size to test whether you've exceeded it.

```
$ echo -e "12\n1234"
12
1234
$ echo -e "12\n1234" | xargs echo
12 1234
$ echo -e "12\n1234" | xargs  -x echo        # no effect
12 1234
$ echo -e "12\n1234\n13" | xargs -s 8 echo   # process valid args until an error occurs
xargs: argument line too long
12
$ echo -e "12\n1234" | xargs -s 8 -x echo    # error and exit
xargs: argument line too long
```

Comment: You example shows the difference. However, I still cannot explain why this gives 1 - 11:

    `(seq 11; echo -e "1234111";seq 12 15)  | xargs -s 11 echo`

but this gives 1 - 9:

    `(seq 11; echo -e "1234111";seq 12 15)  | xargs -s 11 -x echo`

Will `-x` always only give a difference of one single line (namely the line that would have been too long)? I had sort of expected 12 - 15 to be in one of them.

Comment: Use of `-x` only makes sense with `-n <argumentCount>`. Without `-n`, `-x` is pointless, because GNU `xargs` _always_ exits with an error when it encounters a _single_ argument that would result in a too-long command for implied or specified byte-size limit. Thus, `# error and continue` is misleading in your example, because the command will _not_ continue: try `echo -e "12\n1234\n13" | xargs -s 8 echo` - `13` is _not_ printed.
The fact that _with_ `-x`  the _previous_ argument is _also_ not processed (as of v4.2.2), as explained in @Armali's answer, is likely a bug.

Comment: @mklement0: I agree that "continue" is incorrect. It actually processes all valid arguments which appear *before* the one that causes the error, which is then fatal. I think there might be some rare use case for `-s` without `-n` in which you want that behavior, but I can't think of a specific example. Note that it is still possible to have a fatal error with `-s` and `-n` in combination.

Comment: While it _appears_ in your example that `xargs -s 8 -x echo` processes _no_ arguments, it actually does: simply prepend another 2 arguments , and you'll see that they _are_ processed: `echo -e "0\n1\n12\n1234" | xargs -s 8 -x echo`. Adding `-x`, as stated, simply also suppresses the - valid - command _right before_ the offending one, which smells like a _bug_. Using `-x` in this scenario not only shouldn't be necessary, but actually introduces unwanted behavior (due to the bug). Yes, `xargs`, irrespective of options, exits with an error whenever even a _single_ argument doesn't fit.

Comment: Let me try to state it differently: If you set a size limit with `-s <byteCount+1>`, `xargs` will _invariably_ enforce it for you - no `-x` needed.
`-x` is only needed if you _additionally_ want to enforce _use of a specified number of arguments per invocation_ (`-n <argCount>`) without breaking the size limit.

Comment: @mklement0: Well that's weird and is definitely a bug.

Comment: Please consider revising your answer. As it stands, the examples show not only unnecessary use of `-x`, but also misconstrue a bug as by-design behavior. It leads readers looking for the proper use of `-x` down a wrong path.

Answer (score 1):

> I still cannot explain why this gives 1 - 11:
>
> ```
> (seq 11; echo -e "1234111";seq 12 15) | xargs -s 11 echo
> ```
>
> but this gives 1 - 9:
>
> ```
> (seq 11; echo -e "1234111";seq 12 15) | xargs -s 11 -x echo
> ```
>
> Will `-x` always only give a difference of one single line (namely the line that would have been too long)?

This depends of course on the kind of `xargs` you're using, but the prevalent GNU findutils' `xargs` (which may well be the one you have) has exactly this behavior, violating the principle of least astonishment: It accumulates a command line in memory by repeatedly reading the next input item and appending it to the existing command line until it doesn't fit in the line length… Now, it checks whether the read item wouldn't even fit in a line as a single argument (which is the case with `echo 1234111` in your example):

```
      if (p >= endbuf)
        {
          exec_if_possible ();
          error (EXIT_FAILURE, 0, _("argument line too long"));
        }
```

(the above code is near the end of function `read_line()` in findutils-4.6.0/xargs/xargs.c, nearly same in findutils-4.4.2)

```
static void
exec_if_possible (void)
{
  if (bc_ctl.replace_pat || initial_args ||
      bc_state.cmd_argc == bc_ctl.initial_argc || bc_ctl.exit_if_size_exceeded)
    return;
  bc_do_exec (&bc_ctl, &bc_state);
}
```

Here's where option `-x` (corresponding to `bc_ctl.exit_if_size_exceeded`) makes a difference - with `-x`, `exec_if_possible()` just `return`s without `bc_do_exec()`ing the already accumulated well-formed command (`echo 10 11` in your example). Then after `return`ing, the function `error()` exits the `xargs` program.

> I had sort of expected 12 - 15 to be in one of them.

Because said `xargs` *always* exits if an input item is too long by itself, all following items are lost.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr**

- **Use of `-x` only makes sense with `-n <argumentCount>`**: **`<argumentCount>` arguments, if available, *must* fit on a single command line**, based on either the implicit byte-count maximum or an explicitly specified `-s <byteCount+1>` option; if not, `xargs` exits with an error.
  *Without `-x`*, a command line with *fewer* arguments would be constructed, and no error would occur - unless not even a *single* argument fits - see next point.

  - Note that `-x` logic *implicitly* applies to the `-L <lineCount>` and `-I <placeHolder>` options.
  - *Caveat*: As of OSX 10.11.3 and PC-BSD 10.1, the combination of `-x` and `-n` appears to be *broken* in the *BSD* implementation of `xargs` - see below.
- **Without `-n`, there is NO reason to use `-x`**, because both `xargs` implementations *always* exit with an error when they encounter a *single* argument that would result in a too-long command for the overall byte-size limit (again, either implied or specified with `-s <byteCount+1>`).

  - *GNU* `xargs`:  `-x` without `-n` **surfaces a *bug*** (as of v4.2.2), as unearthed in [Armali's hepful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35063271/45375).
  - *BSD* `xargs`: `-x` without `-n` is **syntactically not supported**.
  - Simple example that shows for both implementations that, even without `-x`, a single too-long argument causes an error:

    - `$ echo 1 10 | xargs -s 7 echo # max. command length is 6 (7 - 1) bytes
      1 # ok: 'echo 1' is 6 bytes
      xargs: argument line too long # 'echo 10' is too long`

---

The following *GNU* `xargs` examples:

- specify that a succession of 2 arguments, if available, *should* be used, *if possible* (*without* `-x`) or *must* be used (*with* `-x`) for each command instance: `-n 2`
- limit each command to not more than 8 (9 - 1) bytes: `-s 9`

<sup>Note: With *BSD* `xargs`, the *no* `-x` example below works the same, and the `-x` example *should* work, but doesn't with the `xargs` version found on OSX 10.11.3 and PC-BSD 10.1: whenever `-x` is specified, the specified `<argumentCount>` value in `-n <argumentCount>` is ignored and `xargs` behaves as if `-n 1` had been specified.</sup>

```sh
# NO -x: Use 2 arguments *if possible*.
$ echo -e "1 2 3 4a 5 6" | xargs -n 2 -s 9  echo
1 2
3    # 'echo 3 4a' is more than 8 (9 - 1) bytes -> '3' is used *alone*
4a   # 'echo 4a 5' also doesn't fit -> '4a' is also used alone.
5 6

# WITH -x: *Must* use 2 arguments (if available); *fail* otherwise.
$ echo -e "1 2 3 4a 5 6" | xargs -n 2 -s 9 -x echo
xargs: argument list too long  # 'echo 3 4a' is too long; cannot use 2 arguments -> error
1 2
```

Note how the error message is curiously printed *before* the last successfully executed command; this is possibly connected to the bug mentioned above, so [Armali's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35063271/45375) may offer an explanation.